# Another term for "middle to upper management"?

Tags: idioms, synonyms, professions

I'm trying to express a vocational range of experience.

Can anyone conceive of an alternative way of articulating the following:

> Middle to upper management.

I conducted a browser search but this did not yield the required results.

Comment: middle-range or senior executive level ?

Comment: I would describe the range in terms of number of managers reporting to the candidate and size of the organization under the candidate.

Comment: @Graffito Thanks. Though "executive" is a legitimate synonym, it always sounds more like an entry-level position due the ubiquitous use of "sales executive".

Comment: @jxh Could you provide an example?

Comment: *Candidate must have directed at least 3 managers, and responsible for a team of at least 50, with a discretionary budget of $100,000 per quarter", or something like that.

Comment: It may not be formally part of the definition, but in my experience ***line management*** generally doesn't include "junior" management (those lesser beings who have responsibility for the *work* done by others, but don't have direct authority to hire & fire).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting terminology. Thanks. Found more context on your suggestion [here](http://management.about.com/od/careerdevelopment/g/Line-Manager.htm).

Comment: @Claurus: Good find. I see it says there *[line managers] do not discipline the employee, promote/demote them, do salary adjustments, etc.*, which suggests even they aren't high enough for your context. I guess I was contrasting line managers with, say, "project managers" (who barely have any responsibility apart from overseeing the work itself).

Answer (score 1):

**Administration** - a group of people who manage the way a company, school, or other organization functions (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Does "administration" necessarily differentiate from lower management roles such as team leaders?

Comment: My guess is that it varies, but here are some ways to differentiate between administrators and foot soldiers: administrators probably don't punch a time clock; and administrators probably can't join a union.

Comment: Here's an amusing that is probably not appropriate for an Answer: the big cheeses and the medium cheeses.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately thought of a colloquial answer:

The **Higher-ups**

> Noun, informal.
>
> *A senior person in an organization.*
>
> "He gave staff a vacation without getting approval from the higher-ups."

(Oxford English Dictionary)

[image]

Comment: Further exploration of your suggestion [via thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/higher-up) reveals "brass" (as in, "top brass").

Comment: Brass works, but I think more in a military context, or I guess a workplace that has uniform/rank..

Answer (score 0):

Higher management should suffice.  If asked to clarify, define your middle and upper management definitions.  Cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: I'd suggest 'upper-management' as an absolute variant? Higher- is more relative...